# Using data from inspect tool for pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, ui-automation, pywinauto, inspect

I am working to automate an application called MEmu Instance Manager.

For my project, I want to return the amount of instances that exist, along with their names with the pywinauto module and the inspect tool from windows kit.

Based on the Inspect tool, the MEmu application is structured like this

```
MainWindow
    Parent
        Child1
        InstanceArea
            TARGET
            WIDGETS
```

When inspecting the target widgets with the inspect tool, this is what I get.

[image]

The string that I am trying to return is "b__"

How can you use python to return the `Legacy|Accessible.Value` string?
Does the path of the widget need to be specified before doing this?

If so, how? I've read a lot of useful information on the pywinauto guide, but I'm having trouble applying it on MEmu with the information I am getting from inspect.

For example,

[image]

with the information above, I cannot refer to this window with the info provided.

I am a beginner and I've been working on this for a couple of days, and getting nowhere with this. plz help *cries a lil

Answer (score 2):

Probably this way should work:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title='MainWindow')
# app.MainWindow.dump_tree() # useful to get child_window spec for just a copy-paste!

target = app.MainWindow.child_window(title='TARGET', control_type='Edit').wrapper_object()
# maybe try control_type='Text' depending on info from Inspect.exe

# when you found the control, just get the text
target.legacy_properties()['Value'] # .legacy_properties() returns a dict
```

I've not checked it with real app instance. Hope you could adjust it on the edges.

Comment: thanks for your response. i'm not really understanding `app.MainWindow.dump_tree()` when I run this in my script, it returns `Control Identifiers:

Qt5QWindowIcon - 'MEmuConsole'    (L1071, T378, R1803, B870)
['Qt5QWindowIcon', 'MEmuConsoleQt5QWindowIcon', 'MEmuConsole']
child_window(title="MEmuConsole", class_name="Qt5QWindowIcon")` i dont think im getting child windows within child window.

Comment: it's as if the MEmu app is hiding the path where you can find (in my case) the "target" child window. I say this because, when I search for the child window through the main window, it leads me to a dead end where i stop at the `InstanceArea`. there is nothing beyond that. BUT when i go from the child window(by clicking edit name), up, i am in the right path.

Comment: Well, it's pretty often case for Qt5 apps. We've implemented method `.from_point(x, y)` that can help to find such a "hidden" children elements. It will be available in 0.6.6 soon. Or you can install pywinauto from master branch.

Comment: Also make sure you're connected to the right process: get `app.MainWindow.process_id()` and compare with `Inspect.exe` property `ProcessID` for the target. Though child elements search should work across process bounds, the target might be a child of another top window.

Comment: awesome! looking foward to 0.6.6. I matched the id from `app.MainWindow.proccess_id()` and it matches with the `ProcessID` from Inspect. All children window also have the same ID.

Comment: Just FYI, release 0.6.6 is out about one month ago.